# Move the content of generated asp.net content to the left

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to move the content of my generated asp.net code on all my pages to the left so i use the place on the screen more efficient.

I tried to find some kind of css but i wasnt successful. I want a solution where i need to write it once for all of my views

I made a screenshot to show you what I mean

now it looks like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfe4x.jpg

[But i want to look it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwyHQ.png)

How can i move the created content to the left?

Comment: Share us what you have tried so far and create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Impossible to help you via images alone. Please include your relevant html markup and css

Comment: I tried to but i couldnt add more than two links in my first question 

This is my generated view
http://paste.ofcode.org/38svyEAqqnv6iecPY8CgiBc 

And this is my Layout.cshtml
http://paste.ofcode.org/xb8d8JMdbDxzMAqVZjk6Xw

Actually everything is default now

Comment: Please avoid showing codes as image, especially in image hosting services with dynamically generated link which sometimes deleted/expired without any notice. You may copy and paste code in your question as an edit, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: I know but imgur will not expire so fast :p
yes but its like 2 sites of code

Answer (score 0):

Your page content (table) seems to be wrapped in a bootstrap `.container` div.
Try changing it to `.container-fluid`, it'll use the entire screen width.

Comment: In my bootstrap.css I changed .container to .container-fluid but it didn't change anything. 

Am i missing something?

Comment: You shouldn't change it in your css, you should change it in your html, to use the .container-fluid class instead of the .container class.